# Why is requestHeaders undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which records request headers.

In my background.js file I have this code

```js
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(function(res){
    res.requestHeaders.forEach(header => {
        headers.push(header)
    })
}, {urls : ["<all_urls>"]})
```

But res.requestHeaders returns undefined (cannot read property forEach of undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be specified in the third parameter of addListener:

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
  fn,
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['requestHeaders']);
```

To modify the response you'll need to add "blocking" in the parameter and "webRequestBlocking" in manifest's permissions, see the [webRequest documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) for more info.

To process special headers (`cookie`, `referer`, etc.) in modern versions of Chrome you'll need to specify `extraheaders` as well, and if you want to support old versions of Chrome do it like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(fn, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
}, [
  'blocking',
  'requestHeaders',
  chrome.webRequest.OnSendHeadersOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS,
].filter(Boolean));
```