# Firefox - webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, webextension-polyfill

I'm getting this in Firefox while in Chrome the same works

> Error: Type error for parameter filter (Error processing urls.0: Expected string instead of undefined) for webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.

```
    import browser from "webextension-polyfill";
    
    browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
      listener,
      {
        urls: [url],
      },
      ["requestHeaders", "blocking", "extraHeaders"]
    );
```

I verified the url is a string, any idea where this is from?

Comment: Firefox uses its own WebExtensions API which is different from Chrome's so it doesn't support `extraHeaders`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59589723) for a universal approach.

Comment: Still seem to be getting this after fixing like you suggested, can't determine where this is coming from

Comment: The only other possibility is `url` being undefined.

Comment: Firefox was just being weird, no code changes but and now it works, thanks